# Given a GeoJSON file, how to display only feature centroids in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Ihave the following code:

```
$.getJSON("rodents.geojson",function(data){

  var rodents = L.geoJson(data,{

    pointToLayer : function(feature,latlng){

      var marker = L.marker(latlng);

      //turf.centroid(feature).geometry.coordinates 

  //  marker.bindPopup(feature.properties.Location + '<br/>' + feature.properties.OPEN_DT);
      return marker;
    }
  });
});
```

Actually, I want to pass the LatLng variable by calculating the centroid through this method : `turf.centroid(feature).geometry.coordinates`

PointToLayer takes feature and latlng as parameters, so how can I achieve this ? I tried many things but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me quote from the API docs for [`L.GeoJson`'s `pointToLayer` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#geojson), emphasis mine:

> `pointToLayer`
>   A Function defining how GeoJSON **points** spawn Leaflet layers. It is internally called when data is added [...]
>
> `style`
>   A Function defining the Path options for styling GeoJSON **lines and polygons**, called internally when data is added. [...]

If your GeoJSON does not contain points, then a `L.GeoJSON`'s `pointToLayer` options is not used.

Instead, I'd suggest creating a GeoJSON of centroids from your GeoJSON, for example like so:

```
$.getJSON("rodents.geojson", function(data){

  centroids = {
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: data.features.map(function(feat) {
          return {
              type: 'Feature',
              properties: feat.properties,
              geometry: turf.centroid(feat).geometry
          }
      })
  };

//console.log(data);
//console.log(centroids);

  var rodents = L.geoJson( centroids , { ... });
});
```